# How to expire the session of all users from the admin panel

Tags: java, scala, session, playframework, session-cookies

I am using `scala 2.2` with `play-framework 2.2`

I dont know either it is possible or not but **I have to log-out all users forcefully** from the site. I know this is not going to help me.

```
Redirect("/").withNewSession
```

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation of how you keep track of your users once they log in. Going by the tags to this question, I'm assuming you use cookies. What do you put into their cookies?

Comment: @avik yes i am ussing session-cookies.i store user's userId and username in cookies

Answer (score 1):

Logging out all of your users in one go is indeed possible. The way to do it is to take the information that you use to keep track of your users and invalidate it on the server. With a conventional approach to session management that involves the issuing of [tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_token), this is quite straightforward. However based off [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328804/how-to-expires-the-session-of-all-users-from-the-admin-panel/21354566#comment32184359_21328804) it doesn't sound like you're issuing tokens on the server side, in which case you'll need to think of something a little different.

#### Session management with tokens

A conventional approach to session management is to issue tokens from the server on successful authentication. Say that you store users in a database table. Before they log in, they won't have a token:

```
user   | token          | ...
-----------------------------
govind |                | ...
```

Once a user successfully logs in, the server generates a token (also known as a session ID) and puts it into the record for that user:

```
user   | token          | ...
-----------------------------
govind | jCwEna9FUCex   | ...
```

The server also puts this token into the user's cookie so it now looks like:

```
Cookie: sessionId=jCwEna9FUCex;
```

This token is then used to keep track of the user. Every time someone sends a request to the website, a layer of code on the server performs the following check:

```
if a cookie is present in the request, and it had a session ID that we recognise
  allow request
else
  block request
```

When a user logs out, the actions that were carried out at log-in time are reversed. The token column is cleared in their record in the database:

```
user   | token          | ...
-----------------------------
govind |                | ...
```

The token is then removed from their cookie:

```
Cookie:
```

Now let's return to logging out all users. This can be achieved by clearing the `token` column for all users in the database table. This is something that can be actioned from a HTTP POST request from a screen in the administrator section of your site. Clearing the column would lead to the if-condition mentioned in the pseudocode block above failing for all users.

#### Session management without tokens

The nice thing about tokens is that they can be cleared out without any other side-effects. The problem with what you're storing in your cookies is that invalidating those values (user ID and user name) would have pretty drastic side effects. My advice to you would be to switch to a token-based approach. Above everything else, your approach is not very secure because your cookies can be [replayed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack):

> If I'm a user of your site, I can make a copy of my cookie after I log in for the first time. Even if I log out of your website, as long as I put my cookie back in place I'll actually never need to use my password to get back into the site.

If for some reason you can't change your approach to session management to be token-based, there are other things you can introduce to your site that will simulate the possibilities that tokens give you. These however would be hacks, so I'm not going to propose them! Once again, I would use tokens.